# Import a CSV file to Solr with Camel

Tags: java, csv, solr, apache-camel

Im trying to use Camel-solr to insert a csv file into solr.
I can successfully import the file using post.jar using:

```
java  -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/update/csv  -DfileTypes=csv -jar post.jar 0
```

(where "0" is the filename resulting from a camel.split())

I've tried setting various headers:

```
    .setHeader(SolrConstants.PARAM+"Content-Type", constant("text/csv"))
    .setHeader(SolrConstants.PARAM+"RequestHandler", constant("/update/csv"))
    .setHeader(SolrConstants.PARAM+"stream.contentType", constant("text/csv"))
    .setHeader(SolrConstants.PARAM+"Content-type", constant("text/csv"))
    .setHeader(SolrConstants.PARAM+"content-Type", constant("text/csv"))
    .setHeader(SolrConstants.PARAM+"Content-Type", constant("text/csv"))
    .setHeader("Content-Type", constant("text/csv"))
```

but basically the only way I can get the file imported is if I set the URL to be:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core0?requestHandler=/update/csv
```

Without this on the URL Solr seems to assume its an XML file and so fails to parse it.
"Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'A' (code 65) in prolog; expected '<'"

The URL is going to be spring injected from a properties file, so I dont want to rely on the URL in the file containing the requestHandler.

Any ideas what params I need to set to get this to work as expected?

/edit
Solr 4.2.1
Camel 2.11.1
Java 1.7

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Solr is it? In Solr 4, the CSV handlers were merged into general update handler.

Comment: Sorry edited original to add versions.
Its solr4; I do still have an /update/csv handler defined in solr config, is this incorrect now?

Comment: [It's still there for backwards compatibility](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_4_4_0/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml#L1017), but I recommend using combined handler for new project. It will be much more tested.